# Firebase: Protect creation_date property of a document

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I'm planning to use firebase, but I have security related question.

My documents have `creation_date` property and it is filled with `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` when document created. 
Can I be sure that user will not reverse engineer my webapp to somehow insert fake date? And protect this field from future edits.

Comment: Data Security in Firestore is guaranteed if you set Security Rules to your database. I recommend reading the [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `request.time` variable in the security rules for validating the value of the timestamp. From the [reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#properties):

> The `time` variable contains a timestamp representing the current server time a request is being evaluated at. You can use this to provide time-based access to files, such as: only allowing files to be uploaded until a certain date, or only allowing files to be read up to an hour after they were uploaded.
>
> ```
> // Allow a read if the file was created less than one hour ago
> allow read: if request.time < resource.data.timeCreated + duration.value(1, 'h');
> Many functions are provided to write rules using timestamps and durations.
> ```

Comment: So with this I can restrickt document field "created_at" to be only and exactly current server timestamp of document creation. And forbid future edits of this fields.